# 2nd ToolStripStatusLabel is not visible

Tags: visual-studio-2010, statusstrip, toolstripstatuslabel

I have a small app developed in VS 2010 with a StatusStrip at the bottom.  I want to have two ToolStripStatusLabels in this StatusStrip, one always to the far left and one always to the far right.

I added the two ToolStripStatusLabels and set the Spring property of the first one to True, so that the second one is pushed over to the right.  This works in my IDE and when I run the application on my Win7 computer.  However, when I put this same application on another Win7 machine, the second ToolStripStatusLabel is always invisible.  I changed the BackColor of both labels to something different and I could see both on my machine.  On the problem machine, the 2nd one is completely invisible (no background color, just the Control color, no text).

I have experimented with various values in the StatusStrip's LayoutStyle property.  If it is set to "Flow", the 2nd label *does* show up, but the first label is now all the way on the left, with the 2nd one right next to it.  Again, I want the 2nd one to be all the way on the right.

Clearly, I do not have the right combination of settings to do this, but I am getting frustrated.  I would appreciate any suggestions anyone might have.  Thanks!